# How to only show few characters when pasting text in editor?

Tags: javascript

trying to **paste** characters and if it is more than 50 characters **ONLY show the first 50 characters**. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Here's my code: [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/2ftroyuv/2/)

```
CKEDITOR.instances.foo.on('paste',function(event){

    alert('paste');
    var deleteKey = 46;
    var backspaceKey = 8;
    var keyCode = event.data.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === deleteKey || keyCode === backspaceKey)
        return true;
    else
    {
        var textLimit = 50;
        var str = CKEDITOR.instances.foo.getData();
        if (str.length >= textLimit)
        // Need to add code here to only show the first 50 characters
            return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i am not familiar with CK editor but first you should clear the editor & then insert content. i use tinyMCE & it has insertContent to add text. hope this will help

Comment: Thank you, learned CK Editor a bit.ere is what I did http://jsfiddle.net/pcr56b2k/  Hope this helps. Also you need to properly trim when the user pastes and there is already something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `event.data.dataValue` to get and set data from CKEditor

```
CKEDITOR.instances.foo.on('paste',function(event){
  var textLimit = 50;
  var str = $(event.data.dataValue).text();

   if (str.length >= textLimit) {
    event.data.dataValue = str.substr(0 , textLimit);
  } 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2ftroyuv/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WORDCOUNT` plugin of `CKEditor` and you can find the example

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount

Comment: I dont want to use any third party plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
the document show about paste event.
```

https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_clipboard.html#the-paste-event

```
you could use event.data.dataValue to get the paste content.
code is here:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2vzkLb8L/2/

```
CKEDITOR.instances.foo.on('paste',function(event){
    var pasteContent = event.data.dataValue;
    var str = CKEDITOR.instances.foo.getData();
    var textLimit = 50;
    var newcontent = pasteContent + str; 
    CKEDITOR.instances.foo.setData(newcontent.slice(0,50))
});
```